# SCSS adding a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

im making a calculator app and im trying to add a class for a "main". So basically i made a working script in JS which allows me to switch between several "main" classes (depends on what color theme i click).  Unfortunately it does not see variables inside a class ".dark" (and probably other ones as well). When i put them in global scope it obviously works but not inside theme classes. Themes are placed inside additional scss file. Im probably making a stupid mistake but cant figure it out. For now i left the variables in global scope to make it working.

live site: https://adrian397.github.io/frontEndMentorChallenges/calculator-app-main/index.html

```css
SCSS FILE
@use './themes' as *;

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
}

main {
  background: $mainBackground;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: $default;
}

.calc-container {
  min-height: 55vh;
  width: 28%;

  header {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 10vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    .theme-toggler {
      display: flex;
      h2 {
        font-size: 12px;
        align-self: flex-end;
        margin-right: 1rem;
      }

      .label-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        text-align: center;

        .label {
          margin: 0rem 0.35rem;
        }
      }

      .input-container {
        width: 60px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: $keypad_toggle_Background;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-evenly;

        .input {
          appearance: none;
          background: $equal_toggle_KeyBackground;
          width: 15px;
          height: 15px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          opacity: 0;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .input:checked {
          opacity: 1;
        }

        // .input.active {
        //   opacity: 1;
        // }
      }
    }
  }

  .screen {
    min-height: 10vh;
    width: 90%;
    background: $screenBackground;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .button-container {
    min-height: 40vh;
    width: 90%;
    background: $keypad_toggle_Background;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    padding: 1.5rem;
    grid-gap: 1rem;

    .button,
    .reset,
    .equal,
    .delete {
      border-radius: 10px;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: $normalKeyBackground;
      box-shadow: 0 5px $normalKeyShadow;
      text-align: center;
    }

    // button {
    //   font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    // }

    .reset,
    .delete {
      background: $removeKeyBackground;
      box-shadow: 0 5px $removeKeyShadow;
    }

    .equal {
      background: $equal_toggle_KeyBackground;
      box-shadow: 0 5px $equalKeyShadow;
    }

    .reset,
    .equal,
    .delete {
      color: $default;
    }

    .button {
      color: $normalKeyText;
    }

    .reset {
      grid-column: 1/3;
    }

    .equal {
      grid-column: 3/5;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
_themes.sccs FILE

$mainBackground: hsl(222, 26%, 31%);
$keypad_toggle_Background: hsl(223, 31%, 20%);
$screenBackground: hsl(224, 36%, 15%);

$removeKeyBackground: hsl(225, 21%, 49%);
$removeKeyShadow: hsl(224, 28%, 35%);

$equal_toggle_KeyBackground: hsl(6, 63%, 50%);
$equalKeyShadow: hsl(6, 70%, 34%);

$normalKeyBackground: hsl(30, 25%, 89%);
$normalKeyShadow: hsl(28, 16%, 65%);

$normalKeyText: hsl(221, 14%, 31%);
$default: hsl(0, 0, 100%);

// .dark {
//   $mainBackground: hsl(222, 26%, 31%);
//   $keypad_toggle_Background: hsl(223, 31%, 20%);
//   $screenBackground: hsl(224, 36%, 15%);

//   $removeKeyBackground: hsl(225, 21%, 49%);
//   $removeKeyShadow: hsl(224, 28%, 35%);

//   $equal_toggle_KeyBackground: hsl(6, 63%, 50%);
//   $equalKeyShadow: hsl(6, 70%, 34%);

//   $normalKeyBackground: hsl(30, 25%, 89%);
//   $normalKeyShadow: hsl(28, 16%, 65%);

//   $normalKeyText: hsl(221, 14%, 31%);
//   $default: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
// }
// .light {
//   $mainBackground: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
//   $keypad_toggle_Background: hsl(0, 5%, 81%);
//   $screenBackground: hsl(0, 0%, 93%);

//   $removeKeyBackground: hsl(185, 42%, 37%);
//   $removeKeyShadow: hsl(185, 58%, 25%);

//   $equal_toggle_KeyBackground: hsl(25, 98%, 40%);
//   $equalKeyShadow: hsl(25, 99%, 27%);

//   $normalKeyBackground: hsl(45, 7%, 89%);
//   $normalKeyShadow: hsl(35, 11%, 61%);

//   $normalKeyText: hsl(60, 10%, 19%);
//   $default: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
// }
// .saturated {
// }
```

```js
let input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
let input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
let input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
let main = document.getElementById("main");
input1.checked = true;

function setColorTheme() {
  if (input1.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("dark");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("dark");
  }
  if (input2.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("light");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("light");
  }
  if (input3.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("saturated");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("saturated");
  }
}

setColorTheme();

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="theme"]').forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("change", setColorTheme);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
}

main {
  background: #3a4764;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.calc-container {
  min-height: 55vh;
  width: 28%;
}
.calc-container header {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler {
  display: flex;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .label-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .label-container .label {
  margin: 0rem 0.35rem;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #232c43;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container .input {
  appearance: none;
  background: #d03f2f;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container .input:checked {
  opacity: 1;
}
.calc-container .screen {
  min-height: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
  background: #182034;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.calc-container .button-container {
  min-height: 40vh;
  width: 90%;
  background: #232c43;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.calc-container .button-container .button,
.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .equal,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eae3dc;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #b4a597;
  text-align: center;
}
.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  background: #637097;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #404e72;
}
.calc-container .button-container .equal {
  background: #d03f2f;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #93261a;
}
.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .equal,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  color: white;
}
.calc-container .button-container .button {
  color: #444b5a;
}
.calc-container .button-container .reset {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.calc-container .button-container .equal {
  grid-column: 3/5;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Calculator app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="main">
      <div class="calc-container">
        <header>
          <h1>calc</h1>

          <div class="theme-toggler">
            <h2>THEME</h2>

            <div>
              <div class="label-container">
                <label for="input1" class="label">1</label>
                <label for="input2" class="label">2</label>
                <label for="input3" class="label">3</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-container">
                <input id="input1" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
                <input id="input2" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
                <input id="input3" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>

        <div class="screen">
          <div class="screen-one">3232</div>
          <div class="screen-two">dsa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
          <button class="button">7</button>
          <button class="button">8</button>
          <button class="button">9</button>
          <button class="delete">DEL</button>
          <button class="button">4</button>
          <button class="button">5</button>
          <button class="button">6</button>
          <button class="button">+</button>
          <button class="button">1</button>
          <button class="button">2</button>
          <button class="button">3</button>
          <button class="button">-</button>
          <button class="button">.</button>
          <button class="button">0</button>
          <button class="button">/</button>
          <button class="button">X</button>
          <button class="reset">RESET</button>
          <button class="equal">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- <script src="./script.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't. Really don't. Don't post 800 lines of code to Stockoverflow and expect anyone here to read it all, debug it for you, and give you the working code. Narrow your question down into a single clear concise question and add only the code snippet that is needed to illuminate the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to SCSS documentation, variables defined within a block are local. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#scope

Comment: Ye, but adding a class to an element shouldnt make the variables in that class visible for that specific element?

Comment: Local scope is between the braces. It won't 'widen' to include other classes assigned to an element.